# Why is the Norwegian speech-to-text using "særskriving" and not correct grammar?

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

When I say compound words to the service, it will almost instinctively add spaces between words that should not be there, as if it was the rule itself. An example is the Norwegian word for console window, which is "konsollvindu" written correctly, but the speech-to-text service writes it as the incorrect "konsoll vindu" instead.

I have tried numerous places to get in contact with someone at Microsoft to fix this, as I am a Norwegian, and a linguist by degree. I can help fix these issues if you don't have anyone internally on this.

**This is extremely important to fix.** So please, fix this, or don't include Norwegian publicly for now.

Comment: [Microsoft's own documentation says to use StackOverflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/support) and there seems to be nowhere else I can contact them about this. I also tried [UserVoice](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/912208-speech-service/suggestions/39042742-norwegian-language-needs-improvement-in-grammar#comments)

Comment: For community help, not for complaints or feature requests :)

Comment: I refuse to pay to report issues through Azure. There must be a way to contact them about this. It's critical for the (potential) usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mr. Lin over at [Cognitive Uservoice](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/912208-speech-service/suggestions/39042742-norwegian-language-needs-improvement-in-grammar#comments) this issue will be addressed within 3-4 weeks. Thank you to all who helped! :3